# Google APP Engine PHP - Is it safe to use for production?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Google APP engine for PHP has been out for a while now but it's still in preview / beta mode.

Does anyone know when it will move to a general release?

Is it safe to build a project with PHP and GAE and use it in production?